# How to decompress CCITT Group 4 Algoritms?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to code decompression CCITT Group4 algorithm using my matlab code editor.
But, I cannot understand decoding mechanism.
when we finish encoding an original binary image, we wil have only encoded binary code.
so, In that code, there are no a0, a1, a2, b1, b2(you know, CCITT G4 elements).
This point is My question. Let me give you an example.
we have compressed code line(0 0 0 1 0 0 1  0 1 1 1 1 1).
Firstly, you can detect "Pass mode codeword(0 0 0 1)",
and "Horizontal mode codeword(0 0 1   0 1 1 1   1 1)".
we can know the decoding code run length about horizontal mode, ("White run length=2 -> 0 1 1 1", "Black run length=2 -> 1 1")
But, How can we know the decoding code run length about pass mode??
I think there is no information about pass mode cord run length. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCITT G4 is a 2-Dimensional image encoding algorithm. The pass code and other codes (e.g. the vertical codes) use the previous line as a reference. After a line is decoded, it becomes the "previous" line and a new "current" line begins.